# Compare enum to enum of another type

Tags: typescript, enums

I'm having enums with identical values but different names:

```
enum EnumA{
  HELLO,
  WORLD
}
enum EnumB{
  HELLO,
  WORLD
}
```

As you they are bot generated by an external source an have the same values, but are used in an component where it can be EnumA or EnumB.

```
let x: EnumA | EnumB = EnumA.HELLO;
// or
let x: EnumA | EnumB = EnumB.HELLO;
```

If I wan to check for HELLO I need to

```
if(x === EnumA.HELLO || x === EnumB.HELLO)
```

**Is there an easier way to do this check or tell typescript that these two enums are identical?**

Something like:

```
const x: EnumA | EnumB = EnumB.HELLO;

if(x === EnumA.HELLO) {
    console.log('they are the same')
}
```

If I try this I get the typescript warning:

> This condition will always return 'false' since the types
>   'EnumB.HELLO' and 'EnumA.HELLO' have no overlap.

But the console.log is called! Demo: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAouEEEDeBYAUFTUASMAyeA8gDTpZQDqhASngCLoC+6oks8AQqhlrgSWSxVaDNMzToAxgHsQAZwAuUAB4AudpARQAPhogcoAXj0cAdHyIBudOgCWAMwAUyo4eNxN5-EQCUUbuQy8tIANsCmIdIA5o4A5AoAFsAAnlAAhgBOwFCJ2XJpEMCxPkxAA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare Enums in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39785320/how-to-compare-enums-in-typescript)

Comment: Not a duplicate because the question is about one enum, this one is for two enums with identical values, wich should be compared

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Union-type variables are [narrowed by control-flow analysis upon assignment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8513).  That means the line

```
const x: EnumA | EnumB = EnumA.HELLO;
```

ends up narrowing the type of `x` all the way to type `EnumA.HELLO`, and it is considered an error to compare two unrelated types like `EnumA.HELLO` and `EnumB.HELLO`.

If you want to prevent this from happening so that `x` can be compared to both an `EnumA` and an `EnumB` you can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) like this:

```
const x = EnumB.HELLO as EnumA | EnumB;
```

Then the comparison will work:

```
if (x === EnumA.HELLO) { } // okay
```

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAouEEEoG8CwAoKUASMAyeA8gDQZYDqhASngCIYC+Goks8AQimTvkaZlEo166JugwBjAPYgAzgBcoADygBeNpHYA6XAUJQAhrI2IoAHxPsA3BgwBLAGZQAFCtXuTCHb0IBKLgLSclIANsBaIVIA5s4ARPIAFsAAnoYATsBQiZmyBhDAsb42ohhAA)

---

But if both `EnumA` and `EnumB` are generated by an external source and you know they will be identical, then it seems like a headache to allow them to appear as different types in the first place.  I don't know enough about your code to suggest how to address this... only import `EnumA` and ignore `EnumB`?  Merge `EnumA` and `EnumB` into a single object and only reference the combined `EnumAB`?  Not sure.

---

Anyway, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: The best solution IMHO to that shitty problem we have. Hope to get ride of the problem...

Answer (score 1):

ok so this

```
const x: EnumA | EnumB = EnumB.HELLO;

if(x === EnumA.HELLO) {
    console.log('they are the same')
}
```

throw error since u are comparing const wich is EnumB.HELLO and ts can see this.

if u get the value from function like this

```
const a = (): EnumA | EnumB => {
  return EnumA.HELLO;
};
const x: EnumA | EnumB = a();

if (x === EnumB.HELLO) {
  console.log('they are the same');
}
```

that's correct and runtime will pass the condition since this is the same number

the other solution is to compare it like number.

```
const x: number = EnumA.HELLO;

if (x === EnumB.HELLO) {
  console.log('they are the same');
}
```

and again runtime will pass the condition since this is the same number...

Comment: I like the solution but it still feels kinda hacky... I was hoping for a online solution :)

Comment: what do you mean by online solution?

Comment: spellchecker... one line solution, so to solve my problem in just one simple line, which is somewhere referenced in the official documantion :) () PS: if nobody gives a better solution I will accapt yours in a few days)

Comment: well the one line solution is const x: number = EnumA.HELLO;... if you compare different enums ts will ofc always throw error. what you want is to compare its numeric value so you can compare different enums value what can be same

Comment: what you did is [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgLhgRhgHxgJhgXiwbgFgAoKATwAcBTGAWzIBVKa9zqQAzeGAeh5igALAJYQYomGBCxUGbHDBlaIAE40ARlWBwQEGp3FhhUYXAA2wgF5wT4GCWFcAFHFw48yAJQwA3iRgwoJAgZlQAdGYgAOZOAEQMImJBACbGwnYA7sJmZvBmGXBkYmpQAK4qYDAA5BzmelUwEMJgwDRCbcxiVZgNCsnVyA2CcABuNFIwIGMqZnAUYbGeJAC+QA) same error since you try to compare exact value what ts can see...